# Syncdb - "DatabaseError: no such table: django_site"

Tags: python, django

So i clone my repo, sourced it, ran pip on its dependencies and synced my db only the sync fails with:

```
DatabaseError: no such table: django_site
```

I checked the path vars in settings.py and it's pointing to my website root, in fact it even creates the db file specified in settings.py `db.sqlite3` in the root when I run sync. If the path is correct and django can create the db file, why can't it populate it? What am I missing here ?

**EDIT**: I have tried commenting out "django.contrib.sites" from my installed apps and running manage.py migrate and migrate sites, I still get the same error and an empty database file.

Comment: did you comment out `sites` from `INSTALLED_APPS `?

Comment: No, why would that be necessary? Does the sites app need to be commented when you sync and then un-commented when you're done? If so, why? I haven't seen anything like that in docs and have never had to do that in tutorials.

Comment: @CrabSpy do you have `south` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @alecxe Yes, i do have south in installed apps. I figured south was to be run after syncing, perhaps I ams wrong. Very little experience with Python/Django.

Comment: @CrabSpy then, you should try running `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py migrate sites`.

Comment: @alecxe Well beans. Guess I need to go read a little more on the subject, i was completely wrong about the order of these processes. Thank yo so much, the StackOverflow community sure is quick and polite. Much love.

Comment: Ugh. Still stuck, i have commented out "django.contrib.sites" in my settings.py and i've tried both "manage.py migrate" and "manage.py migrate sites" and I still get the same "Django Error: no such table: django_site" error. As usual it somehow creates the db before stating that it can't find a table within it.

Comment: `django_site` shouldn't need migrations. You say you "cloned your repo, sourced it", are you saying you have your virtualenv in your repo?

Comment: Try running: manage.py schemamigration sites --auto 
and then: manage.py migrate sites

Comment: If you didn't create the database, delete it and re-run the *syncdb*.

Comment: what's your Django Version?

Answer (score 0):

Give a full traceback and your INSTALLED_APPS, please.

I had the same issue when installing both django-cms and django-debug-toolbar. The problem was in toolbar, so I solved it by deactivating toolbar for suncdb.